# How to extract a number between two different strings

Tags: regex, perl

I am new in Perl and I have a situation where I need to extract a number between two different strings.

I have this string variable:

```
my $var = "1234 23.3\"
```

How can I extract the number between the `white-space` and the `dot`? In the example the output should be 23.

The above var string may vary, so sometimes it may be `123 4.32` or `123 334.4\` in which the output should be 4 or 334 respectively.

Comment: `perl -E '$var = "1234 23.3"; $var  =~ /\s+(\d+)\./; say $1'`

Comment: [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @HåkonHægland - Thanks buddy, that helped me. Go ahead and put this as an answer, I will approve it. And to the rest, thanks for all the negativity on such a simple question. When I ask something more complicated, usually it is not answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

White space can be matched using `\s` backslash sequence, see [`perlrecharclass`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Backslash-sequences):

> `\s` matches any single character considered whitespace

Likewise, a digit can be matched using `\d`:

> `\d` matches a single character considered to be a decimal digit.

To match a period or dot, beware that the dot is a regex meta character, that will match any character (except newline), see [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [`perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), so to match a dot explicitly you should escape it.

Hence, given `$var = "1234 23.3"`,  the following statement:

```
$var =~ /\s+(\d+)\./;
```

should extract the number after the space and before the dot into capture group variable `$1`. See [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more information on the `+` metacharacter and also for information about capture groups.